# Get list of bugs linked to workItems in TFS

Tags: tfs

What would be the query to get list of all bugs linked to particular workitem in TFS 2012?
or any other way to get list?

The process template is MSF for Agile Software Development v6.0.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you looked already in other queries how they are built? Wjhat did you tried already so far or what is the best query you already got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example for looking for work items that have a bug linked to them:

[image: Work items with bugs associated to them]

Make sure you change the query type to *work Items and Direct Links*. You can filter down either the main query, or for the linked work items.